# How do I make a tooltip of the option already selected from a select

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select which has a tooltip applied for each option. I would like to know how to make the tooltip work for the option that is already selected.

```js
$(document).tooltip();
```

```html
<select>
    <option value="one" title="Option one">one</option>
    <option value="two" title="Option two">two</option>
    <option value="three" title="Option three">three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It is really unclear what you're asking. When do you want the tooltip to appear? As with standard tooltip functionality, it will appear when an item is hovered over. What did you want to happen?

Comment: @EGC When running the snippet, I would like the tooltip to appear in the option that is already selected. For now, only the title appears when I open the select and position myself in an option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/),

```
$(document).tooltip();
```

Working sample: https://jsbin.com/pogudavuxu/edit?html,js,output

**Answer:** Update select title on change,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#sel").change(function() {
      this.title = $(this).val();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<select title="one" id="sel">
    <option value="one" title="Option one">one</option>
    <option value="two" title="Option two">two</option>
    <option value="three" title="Option three">three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: But I would like the tooltip to also appear in the option that is selected, without having to open the select to see the tooltip

Comment: @DamianRicobelli you can update select title on change.